# Wordpress Admin: filter posts based on user login

Tags: wordpress

I used CCTM plugin and I created several custom post types out of it. In each post type, there's a custom field named location.

I need to filter the lists of the posts by location - depending on the logged in user.

For example, there are 35 posts with common location names (as set in the custom field):
20 posts = location is "Japan"
15 posts = location is "Korea"

When admin logs in, he should see all 35 posts.
When japan_admin logs in, he should see 20 posts only, those with location name as "Japan".
When korea_admin logs in, he should see 15 posts only, those with location name as "Korea".

Please help and share any idea on how to do this. I have searched a lot today and found no available plugin related to this. Might need to do wp hooks?

Answer (score 1):

add a extra contact filed name country first. then the code below make help you.

```
<?php 
function my_user_contactmethods($user_contactmethods ){
$user_contactmethods ['coutry'] = 'Coutry';
return $user_contactmethods ;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','my_user_contactmethods');

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$location = $current_user->coutry;

if(current_user_can('manage_sites')){
query_posts('per_page_posts=-1&post_type=all you post type name');
}elseif($location = 'Japan'){
   query_posts('per_page_posts=-1&post_type=all you post type wanna show the  japanese    guys');
 }elseif($location = 'Korea'){
query_posts('per_page_posts=-1&post_type=all you post type wanna show the korean        guys');
 }
while(have_posts()):the_post();
//normal code ...
endwhile;   
?>
```